# Add decimal places to mean

Tags: numpy, decimal, mean

I'm trying to collect some SMA data. Currently, the decimal place is auto limited to

```
0.000062
```

I need 2 more decimal places:

```
0.00006283
```

Here is my code:

```
symbol_df['5sma'] = symbol_df['close'].rolling(5).mean()
```

I've tried round, but no matter how high I set it, it's still limited to (6) decimal places.

Comment: What does `symbol_df['close'].dtypes` return?

Comment: It returns  `'numpy.dtype' object is not callable `

Comment: Then you put brackets after the dtypes. try `print(symbol_df['close'].dtypes)`

Comment: It's still causing errors. The data gets written to an output file as a string, so I'm not sure  I cant have a (print)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out. I just placed it before the code and the correct decimal places were shown.

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 8)
```